# Use hook to overwrite plugin settings - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, add-filter

Hey there im just using a plugin and I want to overwrite some hook / filter.

I need to overwrite this line – I want to add a custom to email address in my functions.php

https://github.com/bookingactivities/booking-activities/blob/1.12.5/functions/functions-notifications.php#L736

What is the “right” way to do that?

What i tried so far – i think that goes in between – cause mails sending stop

```
function bookacti_email_custom_mailto($data) {
    $mess = $data;
    mail('MAIL@MAIL.com', 'Test', $mess);
    }

add_filter( 'bookacti_email_notification_data', 'bookacti_email_custom_mailto', 99, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I miss that there are 3 arguments passing. Now i got the mail - I will try the rest with setting own to :)

```
$notification, $tags, $locale 

function bookacti_email_custom_mailto($notification, $tags, $locale) {
    mail('MAIL@MAIL.com', 'Test', 'Test');
    }

add_filter( 'bookacti_email_notification_data', 'bookacti_email_custom_mailto', 99, 3 );
```